# Rails Associations and db design for Quiz Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I am building this quiz application. I want it to be kinda sophisticated.

I have come up with this database schema. But I am really confused.. Confused about what associations I would be needing and stuff.

Well.. one thing to note is, when a test is created there is no information regarding the number of candidates who will take it. So, I created the `test_questions` and `candidate_answers` as separate tables.

Please help me with the associations.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see, that would be:

```
# For Questions: 
:has_many => :answers
:belongs_to => :test_question
  # questions table should have the "test_question_id" column

# Answers:
:has_many => :candidate_answers
:belongs_to => :question 
  # Answers table should have the "question_id" column

#Test Questions:
:has_many => :questions
:has_many => :candidate_answers
:belongs_to => :test
  # test questions table should have the "test_id" column but not the "question_id"

#Tests: 
:has_many => :results
:has_many => :test_questions
:has_many => :candidates, :through => :results, :foreign_key => "candidate_id" #why not? ^^

#Results
:belongs_to => :test
:belongs_to => :candidate
  # Results table should have the "test_id" and "candidate_id" columns

#candidate_answers 
:belongs_to => :candidate
:belongs_to => :test_question
:belongs_to => :answer
  # candidate_answers table should have the "test_question_id", "candidate_id" and "answer_id" columns

#Candidates
:has_many => :candidate_answers
:has_many => :results
:has_many => :answered_tests, :class_name => "test", :through => :results, :foreign_key => "test_id" # again, why not?
```

And with the information you gave, that should do what you want. ;)

Comment: In fact you almost did all the job with your database schema, I just guessed that you have a list of questions that you can choose for each unique tests that why you have the "test_questions" table. So that also why you have the candidate_answers table, because each candidates can answer each questions of each tests. It's true, it was quite complicated, but in fact not so much when you have the logic. You should have given a little more info about that. ;-)

Comment: Im sorry. I think I should have explained the schema. And well done reading into the logic :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

- Drop `candidate_answers.test_question`
- Drop the `candidate_answers` table
- Drop the `test_questions` table

  class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :results
    has_many :questions
  end

  class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :test
    belongs_to :candidate
  end

  class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :results
    has_many :answers
  end

  class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
    belongs_to :candidate
  end

  class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :test
    has_many :answers
  end

It looks like you were intending to reuse the answers for more than one question, that would be a generally bad idea.. Better clone an answer in that case.