# need suggestion schema design for my web app

Tags: java

I have a **quiz** app in development under my belt, but I'm confused of getting schema design correct need help in this case please.
I've *quiz*, *question*, *answer*, and *answerOptions* Entities as following
 *quiz*

```
@Entity
public class Quiz implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long quizId;
    private String quizTitle;   

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quiz", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    private Set<Question> questions = new HashSet<Question>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "quizs", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<History> histories = new HashSet<History>();

    // omitting getters and setters
}
```

*question*

```
@Entity
public class Question implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long questionId;
    private String questionText;
    private Integer questionChoices;
    private Integer questionNumbers;
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "quizId")
    private Quiz quiz;  

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Option> options = new HashSet<Option>();


    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "answerId")
    private Answer answer;

    // omitting getters and setters

}
```

*answerOptions*

```
@Entity
@Table(name="answerOptions")
public class Option implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long optionId;
    private String optionText;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "questionId")
    private Question question;
        // omitting getters and setters

}
```

, *answer*

```
@Entity
public class Answer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long answerId;
    private String answerCorrect;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "answer",  cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Question question;
    // omitting getters and setters

}
```

now every thing works good, but where should I save

1. Number of Correct Answers.
2. Number of Wrong Answers.
3. Result of quiz (Pass/Fail)

Comment: Create a __Result__ entity and then map it to _quiz_ and _user_, that is a raw opinion!

Comment: See this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990835/rails-associations-and-db-design-for-quiz-application

Comment: @ArshadAli any example please in that case.

Comment: I would save these fields in the Quiz entity; logically it makes sense to save fields there.